# How to Select and then add a full table on top of it?

Tags: sql, sql-server

my knowledge with SQL is really basic. I have a problem now though.

So I have two tables:
`Food` and `Vegetables`

`Food` has columns: `name, color, price, weight`
`Vegetables` has columns: `name, color, calories, height`

First, I need a query that selects all entries in `Vegetables`where the `name of Vegetable` `NOT EXISTS` in `Food.name Column`.

I kinda got that with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Vegetables AS v
LEFT JOIN Food AS f
ON f.name = v.name
WHERE f.name IS NULL
```

Okay, so this got me a list of all vegetables currently not in `Food` (when searching based on names).

Now I need to add every result from `SELECT * FROM Food` in front of it. 
So I get every Result of Food + those Vegetable Entries that currently are not in Food.

How would this Query look like? I hope I didnt overcomplicate this!

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: How is the result supposed to look like? The food table has different columns from the vegetables table. Do you just want names? Please show a small example.

Comment: So you want prices and calories to mix up in the same column of the output?

Comment: @GordonLinoff using MS SQL Server

Comment: (By the way: It *is* surprising that you use an anti join instead of a straight-forward `NOT EXISTS` as one would have expected from your explantion. Anti joins are a way re-write `NOT EXISTS` / `NOT IN` queries when the DBMS has runtime issues with them.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner oh. Honestly I really havent used SQL ever and this was a logic that was understandable for me, the commands seem to confuse me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all`:

```
select f.name
from food f
union all
select v.name
from vegetables v
where not exists (select 1 from food f where f.name = v.name);
```

If you want the valid matches first, then:

```
select fv.*
from (select f.name, 1 as ordering
      from food f
      union all
      select v.name, 2
      from vegetables v
      where not exists (select 1 from food f where f.name = v.name)
     ) fv
order by ordering;
```

Only use `select *` if you know that the tables have the same columns in the same order with the same types.

Answer (score 1):

So there are vegetables that are not considered food? Okay ...

If it's just about names, then all food plus all the other vegetables is just a union of the two.

```
SELECT name FROM vegetables 
UNION
SELECT name FROM food;
```

If you need food *before* the non-food vegetables, then you need ranking:

```
SELECT name
FROM
(
  SELECT 'vegetable' as what, name FROM vegetables 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'food' as what, name FROM food
)
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY rank() OVER (ORDER BY MIN(what));
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *
FROM Vegetables WHERE name NOT IN(select name from Food)